# How to get cell border color using npoi to read xls/xlsx

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

Im using npoi to read Excel (xls/xlsx) and replicate it to my windows form app using reogrid control.

This is the code i use to open Excel file:

```
IWorkbook workbookNpoi = WorkbookFactory.Create(FileName)
```

Then i read Excel file by row and cell

```
for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < workbookNpoi.LastRowNum; rowIndex){
   //TODO check for null rows
   .....
   foreach(ICell cell in row.Cells){
      short color = cell.CellStyle.TopBorderColor;
      Console.WriteLine(color);
      //check also for remaining borders
   }   
}
```

Now, the output value is some times 8, and some times 64.
How do i cast this value to System.Drawing.Color.
I will appreciate any help